# Deploy no angular com servidor IIS

Tags: angular, iis

Olá, publiquei uma aplicação angular em um servidor IIS, e ao tentar acessar a URL definida no servidor eu obtenho o seguinte erro:

***Erro apresentado: "Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'TestDrive'"***

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não sei o que fazer, procurei na internet e vi algo sobre rotas. Aqui em baixo deixei os códigos das minhas rotas..

***Códigos das rotas***

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router'
import { Personal, Dealers, Agendamento, Finalizados } from '../2 - WebSite/1 - Formulario';
import { BaseNumerica } from '../1 - Shared';

export const routes: Routes = [
    {path: '', component: BaseNumerica, children: 
        [
            {path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'dados-pessoais'},
            {path: 'dados-pessoais', component: Personal, },
            {path: 'dealers', component: Dealers},
            {path: 'agendamento', component: Agendamento}
        ]
    },
    {path: 'finalizado', component: Finalizados}
];
```

***Chamada das rotas no modulo***

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
    NgxMaskModule.forRoot()
  ],
```

Agradeço desde já...

---

A primeira tela a ser chamada é a de 'dados-pessoais' e não percisa definir a URL, de principio

A partir dai, chamo as outras URL, dessa maneira

***this.router.navigate(['dealers']);***

Comment: Como meu IIS é local, a URL disponibilizada por ele foi: 'localhost/testedrive'

Comment: Coloca por favor o link que utiliza essa rotas, e como está o `<routoutlet>`?

Comment: Guilherme, dá uma olhadinha no meu projetinho de estudo, talvez a algo que possa te ajudar: https://stackblitz.com/edit/meu-projeto-angular-6-iuwsch

Comment: @Marconi, Claro, vou inserir meu código na pergunta e vou da uma lida no seu projeto! Agradeço a ajuda, preciso subir essa aplicação ainda hoje rsrs

Comment: Nele tenho algumas rotas configuradas, veja que no arquivo `app.component.ts` há um tag que chama `<router-outlet>`, está tag é responsável por exibir a página que você acionou através de um link.

Comment: Descobri o problema rs. Na tag, <base> do index.html, estava faltando inserir o nome da pasta dos arquivos.

Comment: Posta a resposta pra gente ver Guilherme!

Comment: Claro @Marconi, postarei loga abaixo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faltava implementar o nome da pasta do repositório dos arquivos, ou seja, a pasta aonde está os arquivos, na tag  ficando desse jeito:

```
<base href="/TestDrive">
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test Drive | Volkswagen</title>
    <base href="/TestDrive">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="TestDrive/assets/img/Icones/volkswagen.ico">
    <link href="TestDrive/styles.3d09bccc9fc7ffe4913a.bundle.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
```